# Google Sheets (or Excel) function for OFFSET(range_name, 0, 0)

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Is there a function in Google Sheets (or Excel) that does the same thing as OFFSET(range_name, 0, 0)? (e.g., return a full array of cells)

I want to return an array with a range_name, but can't seem to find a function that does just that. Using OFFSET is fine, but I'm curious if there something like RANGE(range_name) that just returns the range as is.

Update: as answered below, INDEX(range_name) is the function I was looking for.

Comment: INDEX? What are you trying to do?

Comment: INDEX is the answer I was looking for! In the documentation for INDEX, it only talks about a INDEX(range), as in something like C1:D4, and I didn't know you could insert a range_name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few:

- `{range_name}`
- `ARRAYFORMULA(range_name)`
- `INDEX(range_name)` (as @BigBen said)
- `OFFSET(range_name, 0, 0)`
- `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(range_name, ROWS(range_name), COLUMNS(range_name))`
- `QUERY(range_name, "")`
- `FILTER(range_name, ROW(range_name))`

Any of those will give you a range itself and try to place it on the sheet using a cell with the formula as the top left corner of the range.

Comment: INDEX(range_name) was the answer I was looking for. Thanks for all the other alternatives too!